# How to have a URL like this in Django?

Tags: python, django

How can I have URLs like `example.com/category/catename-operation/` in Django?

Also in some cases the user enters a space separated category, how can I handle that?
E.g if the user enters the category as "my home", then the URL for this category will become 
`example.com/my home/` which is not a valid URL.

How can I handle these things?

Comment: example.com/my%20home/ is a perfectly valid URL, anyway.

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? You have URLs like that by defining them in your urlconf. What is your question?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep your URLs pretty, for example when a user enters "my category" you could have "my-category" instead of "my%20category" in the URL. I suggest you look into SlugField (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) and prepopulating that slugfield using ModelAdmin's prepopulated_fields attribute.

Comment: here is a field that will slugify the content of another field for you, on save: http://gist.github.com/242001

Answer (score 3):

`http://example.com/my%20home/` is a valid URL where space character is escaped and Django will do all escaping/unescaping for you.

Comment: You can you the http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote to quote a URL  correctly.  Within a Django app, simply use http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse to create the proper URL for a specific view function with all of it's arguments filled in and correctly quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slugify template tag within your views to deal with spaces and such like so:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
slugify("This is a slug!") # Will return u'this-is-a-slug'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try an improved version of SlugField called AutoSlugField which is part of [Django Custom Management Command Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/).

Comment: There are a number of AutoSlugField implementations floating around in addition the one in the Django Extensions app -- e.g. the one I use is https://bitbucket.org/neithere/django-autoslug/ -- so you may want to shop around, for the latest and greatest, if you are planning on automatically slugging.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding a URL-friendly name to your category and using that in the URL instead.

As another example you could have `example.com/tv/` and have the category called "Televisions."

Answer (score 0):

> How can I handle these things?

If you want to handle this thing, to obtain my-url, then use the form field clean method to return the valid url. Thats what it is meant for.