# Convert a title with spaces to a url-friendly title like stackoverflows title

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a blog app with a list of the latest post titles. Now the list item should be linked to its content. My problem ([similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788432/how-to-have-a-url-like-this-in-django)) is that if the title has some spaces i get a url with spaces if i use:

```
<a href="{{  i.id  }}/{{  i.title  }}">{{ i.title }}
```

in my template. I could use an additional [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) but i dont want to create the url-friendly title manually. What's the common way to do this?

My models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

My view.py

```
def recentlyBlogged(request):
    lastPosts = Post.objects.filter(publication__gt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30))
    return render(request, "blog/blog.html", {'Posts': lastPosts})
```

My template

```
{% for i in Posts %}
    <ul id="latestPostsList">
        <li class="latestPostsListItem"><a href="{{  i.id  }}/{{  i.title  }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a [`slug`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify).

Try this

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_url', args=(slugify(self.title), ))
```

and in the template,

```
<a href="{{  i.get_absolute_url }}">{{ i.title }}</a>
```

You might have to modify `urls.py` accordingly too

```
url(r'post_url/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', view_name, name="post_url")
```

Comment: Hm, i dont get a link with `<a href="{{  i.get_absolute_url }}">{{ i.title }}</a>` but also no error ;). With `<a href="{{ i.title|slugify }}">{{ i.title }}</a>` it works. Why is the first expression not working :/

Comment: that is because you might not have the url defined. I would recommend to implement it the way I have shown

Comment: Sry i pressed enter instead of shift-enter...and posted too early

Comment: have you defined `get_absolute_url` in the models ?

Comment: what does `print reverse('post_url', args=(slugify(self.title)))` print ? Is that a valid URL ?

Comment: `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` is also imported in models

Comment: I opened a shell by `python manage.py shell` imported my models by `from blog.models import *` and got an object with `i=Post.objects.get(id=1)`. Then i tried `print reverse('post_url', args=(slugify(i.title)))` and got the result `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post_url' with arguments '(u'm', u'y', u'-', u't', u'i', u't', u'l', u'e')' and keyword arguments '{}'`

Comment: You are missing a `,` `args = (slugify(self.title)), )`

Comment: Same result with `print reverse('post_url', args=(slugify(i.title)), )`

Comment: i don't unterstand what you mean :)

Comment: `args=(slugify(i.title)), )` should be `args=(slugify(i.title),))`.

Comment: ah ok, with that i get `/post_url/my-title/`